# Number of matrices satisfying given conditions

Tags: matrices

> Let A be the set of all $3*3$ symmetric matrices all of whose entries
>   are either $0$ or $1$.Five of these entries are $1$ and four of them are
>   $0$.

$1)$ The number of matrices in $A$ is ?

$2)$ The number of matrices A in A for which the system of linear equations $A\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has unique solution is ?

$3)$ The number of matrices $A$ in $A$ for which the above system of linear equations is inconsistent is?

Can someone give me some hints please atleast for the first two parts?

Comment: "Hint": have you tried just writing some of these matrices down? There are not that many, and you might see a pattern.

Comment: There is nothing difficult about this. Just write down the possible matrices (note that they must have one or three 1s on the main diagonal).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you didn't have the symmetric condition, this would be the same as choosing $4$ positions for the $0$'s from the $9$ positions in the matrix.  This would give $\binom{9}{4}=126$ possible matrices.

In your case, however, the matrices are required to be symmetric.  So, we can divide the matrix into the diagonal and the portion above the diagonal, let $n_d$ be the number of $0$'s on the diagonal and $n_u$ the number of $0$'s above the diagonal.  Since the matrix is symmetric, the number of $0$'s below the diagonal is the same as the number above the diagonal.  Hence, $4=2n_u+n_d$.

- If $n_u=0$, then $n_d=4$, but there are only $3$ positions on the diagonal.
- If $n_u=1$, then there are $2$ $0$'s on the diagonal and $1$ above the diagonal.  There are $3$ positions on the diagonal and $3$ positions above the diagonal.  This gives $9$ matrices.
- If $n_u=2$, then there are $0$ $0$'s on the diagonal and $2$ $0$'s above the diagonal.  Since there are $3$ positions above the diagonal, this gives $3$ matrices.